# how to get the completed and remaining times of the playing audio using streamer

Tags: iphone, audio-streaming

i am thinking whether the avaudio player is working for audio url content playing........

i am using streamer to play this one but i am showing audioslider to show playing...

to move slider i want to get the time completed playing by streamer.....

any help appreciated...

Comment: No, `AVAudioPlayer` doesn't work for remote URL streaming. It expects to receive a local file URL. What streaming class are you currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used audiostreamer class from github website its working now.....

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer